# The World Wide Web Publishing Service (WWW Service) did not register the URL

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7

This error is logged once I create a website:

> The World Wide Web Publishing Service (WWW Service) did not register the URL prefix http://*:80/ for site 6. The necessary network binding may already be in use. The site has been disabled. The data field contains the error number.

I followed [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/890015) but there is no `ListenOnlyList`, instead I saw `UrlAclInfo` which contains this:

[image]

```
C:\Users\Administrator>netstat -ano | find ":80" |find /i "listen"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
```

4 is the pid number of `System` process.

Any ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated **[here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569059%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMKCmdLine)** Un-Install Microsoft Web deploy and then Re-Install it using command line with these parameters:

```
msiexec /I <msi_filename> /passive ADDLOCAL=ALL LISTENURL=http://+:8080/MsDeployAgentService2/
```

Answer (score 3):

Check that no existing website is using a binding without a host header on `0.0.0.0` ("All Unassigned").

---

If that's not the case, figure out what process has binded *:80 on your machine by issuing:

`netstat -ano | find ":80" |find /i "listen"`

That will show you the processes listening on :80, the last number in each string is the Process ID that created the given binding

To find a process by its PID, do the following:

- Open **Task Manager** (Run -> taskmgr)
- Go to the "**Processes**" tab
- Click the "**Show processes from all users**" button in the bottom. This will enable you to see all processes(*)
- Select **View** -> **Select Columns** in the menu
- Be sure to have the "**PID (Process ID)**" checkbox checked
- Press "**OK**"

This is the process obstructing your web site from registering its binding correctly

**(*) PROTIP**: Pressing the "**Show processes from all users**" button forces the console to attempt to elevate its privileges, effectively yielding the same call as "*Run as administrator*" in right-click context menus.
If **Task Manager** ever returns "Access is denied", "Access denied", error code 5 or returns nothing when sending messages to other users on a computer, simply press the button and you'll have all your permissions and privileges

Comment: Thank you but No, there is just a default website on `*:80` and if I create another website it will log this error.

Comment: Thanks again, I edited my question and added the result. It's `System` process that's holding `0.0.0.0:80`. I don't think I can stop this process.

Comment: I found out that `Web Deployment Agent Service` and `World Wide Web Publishing Service` are both using this port. so does this help?

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was **Skype** who uses port 80.

So uncheck Skype / Options / Advanced / Connection / **Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incomming connections**.

Now exit Skype, run it again. Everything should work from now.

Comment: Also true of the Skype 'Metro/Modern' app, except there's no obvious option to configure which port it uses

Answer (score 1):

For me, I was in the properties of a startup project trying to change to start up URL when running that site in Visual Studio and it asked permission to change a IIS virtual directory settings for me.

Errors:

```
1. The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Launch 
permission for the COM Server application with CLSID ... (The SMS Agent Host service)

2. Value does not fall within the expected range
```

Fix: 
Backup and Open C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

In system.applicationHost section, find your site ("The Default Site"), and comment out the application you were working on. Start the default site.

[I got the idea to edit the applicationHost.config file here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30344.custom-iis-app-pool-identity-value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range.aspx)